# SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'REQUESTORS' property

Tags: php, xml, soap, lotus-domino

I try to use Lotus Domino V7 Free Time Web service.

**I code this:**

```
<?php
    $soap = new SoapClient('http://foo.com/cppfbws.nsf/busytimelookup?WSDL');

    print_r( $soap->__getFunctions() ); //Array ( [0] => RESPONSESTRUCTURE LOOKUP(REQUESTSTRUCTURE $REQUEST) ) 

    $soap->lookup(array(''), array('Bob'), array(''), '2007-02-26 00:01', '2012-02-26 23:59');

    //or

    $soap->__soapCall('lookup', array(array(''), array('Bob'), array(''), '2007-02-26 00:01', '2012-02-26 23:59'));
?>
```

---

**Results:**

```
Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'REQUESTORS' property
```

Do you have any idea?

---

Only documentations that I have:

***cppfbws.nsf/busytimelookup?WSDL***:

```
<wsdl:portType name="busytime">
    <wsdl:operation name="LOOKUP" parameterOrder="REQUEST">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:LOOKUPRequest" name="LOOKUPRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:LOOKUPResponse" name="LOOKUPResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:message name="LOOKUPResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="LOOKUPReturn" type="impl:RESPONSESTRUCTURE"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="LOOKUPRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="REQUEST" type="impl:REQUESTSTRUCTURE"/>
</wsdl:message>

<complexType name="REQUESTSTRUCTURE">
    <sequence>
        <element name="REQUESTORS" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_string"/>
        <element name="ATTENDEES" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_string"/>
        <element name="DETAILS" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_string"/>
        <element name="START" type="xsd:string"/>
        <element name="END" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

***And this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino7-free-time/***:

```
attendees[0]="Peter Pan"; //name of the first person
attendees[1]="Mary Poppins"; //name of the second person        
requestors[0]="";   //Web service does not require this parameter
details[0]="";   //Web service does not require this parameter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a problem of request format and case sensitivity.

My final code:

```
<?php

    $soap = new SoapClient('http://foo.com/cppfbws.nsf/busytimelookup?WSDL', array('login' => 'root', 'password' => 'root'));

    $request = array('REQUESTORS' => array(''), 'ATTENDEES' => array('root'), 'DETAILS' => array(''), 'START' => '2011-11-30 01:00', 'END' => '2011-12-30 18:00');

    $result = $soap->lookup($request);

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($result->ATTENDEES as $r) {
        echo 'User : '.$r->ATTENDEE.'<br/><br/>';
        foreach ($r->BUSY as $b) {
            echo 'Busy interval #'.$i++.'<br/>';
            echo 'Start : '.$b->START.'<br/>';
            echo 'End : '.$b->END.'<br/><br/>';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: This clued me to the problem I was having.  Thanks!